# How to create .ipa file for testing using Runner.app?

Tags: ios, flutter

I am android developer learning Flutter, and I really have some trouble trying to create debug .ipa file, for testing purposes.

So, I managed to create Runner.app file using command from Terminal:

```
flutter build ios --debug
```

The location of Runner.app file is

> my_project_folder/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app

What to do next?
Also, is there a way to create debug .ipa file from Xcode?
Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`flutter build ipa` is now available and takes an optional `--export-options-plist` flag to make an IPA from the archive bundle. See `flutter build ipa -h` on the master channel for details.

Comment: Seems a good option but it is only supported in macOS :/ :S

Comment: Tip: Easiest way to have ExportOptions.plist is to manually export the IPA from the Runner.xcarchive for the first time, which would generate four files one of them is the export options. Just copy it and keep it in the project to be used with the command in this answer

Comment: After you run flutter build ipa, where is now the directory of the ipa file?

Comment: @a7md0 Can you elaborate?

Comment: @KrishBhanushali If you used their Archiver utility to export the IPA for the 1st time it would output the IPA with other files. One of these files is the plist with the export options. Sorry I cannot get you the exact steps since I do not have access to Mac machine at the moment

Answer (score 90):

You can create **.ipa** file by your self and send iOS build url to your client or other.

Just follow me :)

1) Generate your iOS build by below command
-> [flutter build ios --release/debug](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive)

2) You will found exact path of your **Runner.app** Ex.
-> `Built /Users/UserName/Documents/AppName/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app.`
Just find this **Runner.app** file and do copy/paste it to Desktop.

3) Create folder name is **"Payload"** *(case-sensitive)* on Desktop

4) Move your **Runner.app** File in the **"Payload"** folder.

5) Compress **Payload** folder to default **.zip**

6) Convert/rename **Payload.zip** to **Payload.ipa**

That's it. Now you have to open "[Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/)" and Upload the **Payload.ipa** on it. Wait for **100%** done. Click on **send** button. You will find one url, Send this url to your client or any other person. They can install on his/her device.

> ~ PS : Make sure diawi Url valid for those UDIDs that attached with your provisioning profile. And I haven't tried these steps to upload app on TestFlight/AppStore.

Comment: I can verify that this method works :) If anyone wants a shell script of this answer, see https://gist.github.com/monmonja/6e2910ca51d64b8be8bb8d28d0d34a55

Comment: Does this work with test flight and app store submission?

Comment: I haven't tried yet but defiantly it should be worked.

Comment: getting error "unable install" does not contain application bundle. i have checked ipa file has bundle with name Runner.

Comment: Remember and recheck 3rd step that I mentioned.

Comment: @iPatel Does it work without Apple developer account? Or I have to buy it even if I would like just test my app?

Comment: No you must need to buy Apple developer account, even test your app.

Comment: Doesn't work with Testflight and Appstore: TMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

Comment: sorry I haven't check for upload app on test flight or AppStore. and also it's not good way for upload on testFlight/AppStore. I am using only this way for give build or diawi link to client for the testing.

Comment: the command doesnt work when i submit it in my projects terminal please?

Comment: Don't work unable to install popup show.How solve

Comment: Works for me using https://www.installonair.com to distribute ipa file

Comment: this worked very well

Comment: Can I do this on windows pc as well?

Comment: @saifaly No, You will need a mac to build the ios app.

Comment: worked like a charm ! it can be used for firebase app distribution too

Answer (score 3):

I have a simple implementation combining a Makefile and Fastlane. This way, I can run `make beta` from my project directory to deploy.

`./Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: beta
beta:
    flutter build ipa --export-options-plist=ExportOptions.plist
    cd ios && fastlane beta ipa:../build/ios/ipa/YourBundleName.ipa
```

`./ios/fastlane/Fastfile`:

```
platform :ios do
    lane :beta do |options|
        # ... pre-delivery actions, eg: `match(type: "appstore")`
        pilot(
            ipa: options[:ipa]
            # ... the rest of your pilot configuration
        )
        # ... post-delivery actions, eg: `slack(message: "Uploaded to TestFlight")`            
    end
end
```

Note that I use `match(type: "appstore")`, so that's why you see `signingStyle` as `manual`.

`./ExportOptions.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <true/>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>your.bundle.identifier</key>
        <string>Your Provisioning Profile Name</string>
    </dict>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>iOS Distribution</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>YourTeamId</string>
    <key>thinning</key>
    <string>&lt;none&gt;</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the next bash-script

```
flutter build ios --debug
cd ios
xcodebuild -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner archive -archivePath Runner.xcarchive
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath Runner.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist ../scripts/exportOptions.plist -exportPath ../scripts -allowProvisioningUpdates
rm -fr Runner.xcarchive
```

ipa will be created at '../scripts'. You may have own path.

> -allowProvisioningUpdates is using if you want xcodebuild updates certificates automaticaly.

exportOptions.plist - it's a file with distribution settings.
I use next

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <false/>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>enterprise</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>automatic</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>YOUR TEAM ID</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Note that this actually will build your project twice: once with flutter build ios, and once with xcodebuild -workspace. Both are using different build folders, so each source file needs to be built twice, wasting lots of time and CPU cycles. Hasn't anyone found a better solution?

Comment: Is `flutter build ios` needed?

Comment: My team doesn't does not support enterprise app distribution, so I have changed "method" to "development" just for my purposes :)

Answer (score -1):

These are the next steps outlined in the instructions (which are found here: https://flutter.io/ios-release/):

In Xcode, configure the app version and build:

```
In Xcode, open Runner.xcworkspace in your app’s ios folder.
Select Product > Scheme > Runner.
Select Product > Destination > Generic iOS Device.
Select Runner in the Xcode project navigator, then select the Runner target in the settings view sidebar.
In the Identity section, update the Version to the user-facing version number you wish to publish.
In the Identity section, update the Build identifier to a unique build number used to track this build on iTunes Connect. Each upload requires a unique build number.
```

Finally, create a build archive and upload it to iTunes Connect:

```
Select Product > Archive to produce a build archive.
In the sidebar of the Xcode Organizer window, select your iOS app, then select the build archive you just produced.
Click the Validate… button. If any issues are reported, address them and produce another build. You can reuse the same build ID until you upload an archive.
After the archive has been successfully validated, click Upload to App Store…. You can follow the status of your build in the Activities tab of your app’s details page on iTunes Connect.
```