# flutter app in android studios (windows) to flutter app for iOS (.ipa)

Tags: android, ios, xcode, macos, flutter

I just finished my flutter app in android studios (windows) and published it in the Play Store.
Now I want it to appear in the Appstore as well. I got my hand on a mac, but don't know what to do now.
Simply install android studios, open the exact same folder in there and build an iOS app?
Do I need to install Xcode?
Searched for a while now, but couldn't figure out what to do.
If any developer knows the answer I'd be pretty thankful!

Comment: Yes , you need xcode to generate ipa , This article might help - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254470/how-to-create-ipa-file-for-testing-using-runner-app/56666092)

Comment: You need to do same for iOS.  Open project in Xcode, Configure all the certificates and upload it to App Store.

Comment: please follow this : https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos