# There's been an error parsing your app's provisioning profile. Ensure you are uploading a validly signed IPA and try again

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I have a problem while trying to upload my application to firebase. This is how this error looks like:

[image]

And actually I have no idea why it happens. Could it be because of development certificates? Or could it be because of packages versions?

I have done everything according to Firebase SDK instructions, but it still doesn't work. Also, the problem is, that I just can't find any info about this error in internet. So, what is the reason of this? And how can I fix that?

PS. By the way, about `.ipa` file. I create it in this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254470/how-to-create-ipa-file-for-testing-using-runner-app).

1. Copy `Runner.app` to desktop.
2. Create `Payload` folder.
3. Paste `Runner.app` in this folder, compress it, and change `.zip` to `.ipa`

Comment: Can you add link with your ipa/zip file?

Comment: Sorry, I can't @Eysner

Comment: Ok, understand, i think you should validate ipa, for example just install that ipa on device and open application.

Comment: What are you using to create this Runner.app. How did you build it? Are you signing this app? If you just copy archive and change name without signing your app it will be rejected because there's no way to verify you actually created this app. Do you have an apple developer account? @Eysner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your [Apple Developer Profile](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list) and make sure you have an active Apple Developer subscription (your $100 (or your local currency) fee is paid), and you have the correct certificates, and signing installed onto your device, and you have a correct bundle ID linked to each of said certificates, etc. If you made any corrections, create a new .ipa file, and retry the upload process.

There is an option in Xcode under Signing & Capabilities to have Xcode manage your provisioning profile.