# Automate flutter build iOS in codemagic

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-ios, codemagic

I'm working on a flutter project and I want to buid an IPA from my windows because I don't have a Mac. So I used codemagic and it works perfectly but my problem is that I did it manually from the website, is there a way to make it automatic like adding a file `codemagic.yaml` in my project route, how can I do it. It's my first time using codemagic any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Dina, I've been trying to build an ipa file using CodeMagic but all I'm getting is a Runner.app folder which I don't know how to use. Can you please tell me how you build an ipa file using CodeMagic?

Comment: All you need to do is to convert the runner.app to an ipa file, and that's so easy just you need to follow some steps. This question will help you to do it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254470/how-to-create-ipa-file-for-testing-using-runner-app. Hope it works

Comment: I've tried this but my app size is too big and Diawi is not taking it, is there any alternative for this Dina?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I had the same problem all the alternatives have a limited size. So I was obligated to use Xcode from a mac to test my application created by Codemagic.

Comment: Can you help me do that on mac?

Comment: @littleironical Sorry for the late answer again, I was searching the video that helped me to do it on mac, so this is the video just follow the steps using the codemagic ipa and it will works perfectly : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIDMgRCEvwU&list=LL&index=7&t=238s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is hosted on Github, you can use it as an action in Github Actions. This way, every time (for example) your project is merged to the `main` branch, it can automatically create the IPA file, and further automate the deployment process.

https://flutterci.com/

Comment: I know my question is I don't want to create the IPA from the website codemagic I want to make it automatic without using the website.

Comment: Which is why I suggest using the Github Action, which will do its thing without you even opening a web browser and allows you to automatically build and deliver the app to the stores

Comment: But its output iz a zip file. How to deal with it?